# Limiting the number of GB to read in read_csv in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I often work with `csv` files that are 100s of GB in size.  Is there any way to tell `read_csv` to only read a fixed number of `MB` from a `csv` file?

#### Update:

It looks like `chunks` and `chunksize` can be used for this, but the documentation looks a bit slim here. What would be an example of how to do this with a real csv file? (e.g. say a `100GB` file, read only rows up to approximately `~10MB`)

Comment: The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) show params for `nrows` and `chunksize`

Comment: Thanks @EdChum I have updated the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `nrows=number_of_rows_to_read` to your read_csv function to limit the lines that are read.

Comment: Thanks @Easypeasy. I have updated the OP to narrow and focus the question to specifically how to limit what we read in size.